# Image height to the other div

Tags: html, css, image, height

I'm new on Stackoverflow, and i need help with these problem.

So the problem is: I want this dashed image height to 100% of the container.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1">

</div>

<aside>
    <?php
    if (logged_in() === true) {
        include 'includes/widgets/loggedin.php';
    } else {
        include 'includes/widgets/login.php';
    }
    include 'includes/widgets/user_count.php';
    include 'includes/widgets/sponsors.php';
    include 'includes/widgets/partners.php';

    ?>
</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
aside {
    width:260px;
    float:right;
    background-image:url(../images/dashed.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    padding-left:15px;
}

#container, footer {
    background:#fff;
    width:1100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
}

#test1 {
height:1000px;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You know there is a `border dashed` property on CSS?

Comment: We need more details about your html. Apparently your 'aside' doesn't have the same height as the '#container'.

Comment: @Danko There is a indeed border dashed, but it is not working for height:100%; and height:auto; it only works with image, so i tried but i still wont come out.

Comment: @Diego I have edited now, is this ok?

Comment: But... where is the #container in your markup?, If the height of #test1 is the same in #container then you should set the aside height as in #test1 (1000px). Otherwise if the height change dinamically you can use this script: document.querySelector("aside").style.height = document.querySelector("#container").offsetHeight + 'px';

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
aside { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-y center center fixed; 
  padding-left:15px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It is not working, i tried and i got aside with grey background. Height is still the same problem

Screenshot: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/fa7x1e/8

Comment: @BartvanderHoeven is better if you include all code on the question or make a fiddle - codepen to reproduce the issue instead of attach a hundred img's

Comment: Okay, sorry. I will do jsfiddle